# Developing the same app for iPhone and iPad: one app for all or two apps per device type?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios-universal-app

I have an order: to develop the app that should work the same on both iPhone and iPad.
I know that there are two approaches on how many apps to do:

- one app for both device type;
- two apps - for iPhone and iPad.

I have seen both approaches met often on App Store.
I want to figure out **which** approach and **when** is better than another.
Could you please help me to understand **pros** and **cons** of each approach and **situations** that are more suitable for the former approach than for the latter one?

Comment: If you are not planing to sell Ipad and Iphone versions separately universal app is the best. Otherwise you have to deal with two different project for same classes etc.

Comment: @mohacs You don't need two projects. Just one with two targets.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for same app on both iPhone and iPad its better to go for Universal application. Its always suggestible to go for Universal application if functionality is same on both iPhone and iPad.

Please go through following documentation by Apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

There are lot of tutorials available on internet about how to create universal applications.